# PostgreSQL: как добавить данные в колонку, которой нет во временной таблице WITH

Tags: postgresql

Я сейчас затачиваю нужный мне запрос под  RedShift.

Сейчас у меня есть уже работающий, который создает временную таблицу с помощью WITH и вставляет из нее данные в ту таблицу, которая мне нужна дальше. Запрос такой:

```
INSERT INTO target.table (
            collect_project_id,
            project_number,
            project_name,
            connect_project_id,
            project_desc,
            project_type,
            project_status,
            project_path,
            language_code,
            country_code,
            timezone,
            date_created,
            date_updated
            )
WITH temp AS (SELECT id, number, name, connect_project_id, description, type, status, path, language, country, timezone, created, modified
FROM source.table)
SELECT id, number, name, connect_project_id, description, type, status, path, language, country, timezone, created, modified
FROM temp;
```

Но мне нужно, чтобы target.table в конце еще была добавлена одна колонка edw_date_created, которой нет в temp (source.table) и в которую данные добавятся через NOW() (то есть в эту колонку будет добавлена дата добавления записи). Не могу понять как это сделать. Буду благодарен за подсказку.

Comment: А это поле в структуре таблицы уже есть?

Comment: да, оно есть в target.table

Comment: Ну тогда измените его определение и добавьте туда `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. А запрос оставьте как есть.

Comment: не могу - у меня нет прав на изменение этих таблиц. я должен работать с тем, что есть. ну, я работаю в большой структуре, тут разделение прав и тд.

Comment: Ну добавьте это поле в список присваиваемых, и нужное выражение (функцию) в список выбираемых.

Comment: *у меня нет прав на изменение этих таблиц. я должен работать с тем, что есть. ну, я работаю в большой структуре, тут разделение прав и тд.* Ну так запросите такое изменение. Вообще странно, что при таком разделении в структуре отсутствуют автоприсваиваемые поля created_at и updated_at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO target.table (
            collect_project_id,
            project_number,
            project_name,
            connect_project_id,
            project_desc,
            project_type,
            project_status,
            project_path,
            language_code,
            country_code,
            timezone,
            date_created,
            date_updated

-- добавить поле
, edw_date_created

            )
WITH temp AS (SELECT id, number, name, connect_project_id, description, type, status, path, language, country, timezone, created, modified
FROM source.table)
SELECT id, number, name, connect_project_id, description, type, status, path, language, country, timezone, created, modified

-- и значение для него
, NOW()

FROM temp;
```

Comment: Да, так получилось.

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk Ну или можно не в основном запросе, а в CTE добавить (`SELECT ... , NOW() AS edw_date_created ...`) - вот только смысла великого не вижу.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше участие и помощь!